# SQL Anomaly Using 'USING' Clause with Nested Queries?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, hsqldb

I have a normalized database containing 3 tables whose DDL is this:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE Clients ( 
    cli_id       INTEGER       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100) PRIMARY KEY,
    defmrn_id    BIGINT,
    lastName     VARCHAR(48)   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    midName      VARCHAR(24)   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    firstName    VARCHAR(24)   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    doB          INTEGER       DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    gender       VARCHAR(1)    NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Client_MRNs (
    mrn_id       BIGINT        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100) PRIMARY KEY,
    cli_id       INTEGER       REFERENCES Clients ( cli_id ),
    inst_id      INTEGER       REFERENCES Institutions ( inst_id ),
    mrn          VARCHAR(32)   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT climrn01 UNIQUE (mrn, inst_id));

CREATE TABLE Institutions ( 
    inst_id      INTEGER       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 100) PRIMARY KEY,
    loc_id       INTEGER       REFERENCES Locales (loc_id ),
    itag         VARCHAR(6)    UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    iname        VARCHAR(80)   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL);
```

The first table contains a foreign key column, defmrn_id, that is a reference to a "default identifier code" that is stored in the second table (which is a list of all identifier codes).  A record in the first table may have many identifiers, but only one default identifier.  So yeah, I have created a circular reference.

The third table is just normalized data from the second table.

I wanted a query that would find a CLIENT record based on matching a supplied identifier code to any of the identifier codes in CLIENT_MRNs that may belong to that CLIENT record.

My strategy was to first identify those records that matched in the second table (CLIENT_MRN) and then use that intermediate result to join to records in the CLIENT table that matched other user-supplied searching criteria. I also need to denormalize the identifier reference defmrn_id in the 1st table.  Here is what I came up with...

```
SQL = SELECT c.*, r.mrn, i.inst_id, i.itag, i.iname 
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN 
  (   
      SELECT m.cli_id   
      FROM Client_MRNs AS m   
      WHERE m.mrn = ? 
  ) AS m2 ON m2.cli_id = c.cli_id 
INNER JOIN Client_MRNs AS r ON c.defmrn_id = r.mrn_id 
INNER JOIN Institutions AS i USING ( inst_id )  
WHERE (<other user supplied search criteria...>);
```

The above works, but I spent some time trying to understand why the following was NOT working...

```
SQL = SELECT c.*, r.mrn, i.inst_id, i.itag, i.iname 
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN 
  (   
      SELECT m.cli_id   
      FROM Client_MRNs AS m   
      WHERE m.mrn = ? 
  ) AS m2  USING ( cli_id ) 
INNER JOIN Client_MRNs AS r ON c.defmrn_id = r.mrn_id 
INNER JOIN Institutions AS i USING ( inst_id )  
WHERE (<other user supplied search criteria...>);
```

It seems to me that the second SQL should work, but it fails on the USING clause every time.  I am executing these queries against a database managed by HSQLDB 2.2.9 as the RDBMS.  Is this a parsing issue in HSQLDB or is this a known limitation of the USING clause with nested queries?

Comment: not every RDBMS supports the using keyword.  If you do a very simple join between two of your tables with that word, does it execute or crash?

Comment: HSQLDB provides support for the USING predicate out of the box.  In the second SQL, there are two USING predicates.  The first one fails, but the second one (which also appears in the working SQL) works just as one would predict that it ought to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try with HSQLDB 2.3.0 (a release candidate).

The way you report the incomplet SQL does not allow proper checking. But there is an ovbious mistake in the query. If you have:

```
SELECT INST_ID FROM CLIENTS_MRS AS R INNER JOIN INSTITUTIONS AS I USING (INST_ID)
```

INST_ID can be used in the SELECT column list only without a table qualifier. The reason is it is no longer considered a column of either table. The same is true with common columns if you use NATURAL JOIN.

This query is accepted by version 2.3.0

```
SELECT c.*, r.mrn, inst_id, i.itag, i.iname 
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN 
  (   
      SELECT m.cli_id   
      FROM Client_MRNs AS m   
      WHERE m.mrn = 2 
  ) AS m2  USING ( cli_id ) 
INNER JOIN Client_MRNs AS r ON c.defmrn_id = r.mrn_id 
INNER JOIN Institutions AS i USING ( inst_id )
```

Comment: fred, thanks for taking the time to reply. Sorry for not being more specific.  The error messages reported by the second SQL are "Error: user lacks privilege or object not found: CLI_ID \n SQL State: 42501 \n ErrorCode: -5501.  I was aware that "USING columns" don't have get<schema>Name values in the resultset metadata ... but they still show up in my resultsets when I name them this way.  I need the keys in my java-side data model, so I've just been going with it.  I'm hearing you say that I should not qualify them with a table name, though.

Comment: Yes, for shared columns in USING, qualitifed names shouldn't be allowed in the select list.

Comment: I should just clarify that even when I correct the column list so that "i.inst_id" becomes "inst_id", the second SQL continues to fail at the 1st USING predicate (same error message), whilst the 1st SQL continues to work as it had been.

Comment: Please try with version 2.3.0

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit that, while I would absolutely love to try out the release candidate, I'm not facile with Maven or snapshot repositories and, even after browsing the HSQLDB user section on using the snapshots and consulting the Maven support documentation for NetBeans ... I'm still lacking.  I'll put some more energy into it this weekend.  I'm eager to try out 2.3.0.

Comment: I can confirm that the USING predicate applied to the result table yielded by the nested query in the second SQL above works as expected in the 2.3.0 snapshot.  Both of the above queries work as one would predict they should.